# How to only change the datepart in a datetime in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Say I have a variable dt that has the correct time component:

```
"1/1/1900 05:00 PM"
```

How do you change dt so that dt gets the right date, without affecting the time.  I need dt to be:

```
"2/13/2014 05:00 PM"
```

EDIT: The time may not be 5:00 PM, it could be anything.

Comment: Have you looked into the [`DateTime` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see what properties and methods are available for that type?

Comment: Yes, asking only after having looked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `DateTime` is immutable - you can't change *any* part of it.

You *can* create a *new* DateTime and change the parts *in transit*:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900 05:00 PM");

// adding DateTimeKind as suggested by comments
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2014, 2, 13, dt1.Hour, dt1.Minute, dt1.Second, dt1.Kind);
```

Comment: You're gonna lose timezone info though.

Comment: +1 for incorporating `DateTime` immutability into the answer. Nice and complete.

Comment: @dcastro `DateTime` doesn't store time zone information, only whether or not it's "local time" or UTC (or unspecified). The `DateTimeKind` should probably be transferred from `dt1` to `dt2` though.

Comment: @dvnrrs added per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

try AddDays or any other AddXXX method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon here at SO.  Try adding the gist of the article to demonstrate the point.

Comment: Bad idea; because of time adjustments (daylight saving changes and so on), adding a day is not guaranteed to result in the same time of day.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900 05:00 PM");
DateTime dt2 = dt1.AddYears(114).AddMonths(1).AddDays(12);
```

Answer (score -2):

We don't know this concrete circumstance. Sometimes we operate with numbers and dates that stored as strings in files, etc. A string way could go like this:

```
string original = "2/13/2014 05:00 PM";
string[] parts = original.Split(); // split by " "
parts[0] = "4/5/2020"; // here can be myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
string newDate = string.Join(" ", parts);
```

Comment: what's the point of this: `new char[] { char.Parse(" ") })` why don't you just: `new char[] { ' ' })`, even you don't need to pass a char array to split method. You can  use: `Split()` It will split by space. from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) `If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters.`

Comment: You'll need to tag @Selman22 to get his attention, otherwise he wont know you changed your answer.

Comment: @Selman22  Interesting. I don't see `Split()` in documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. I guess, I had to dig deeper

Comment: @T.S. because you are looking to the wrong place :) See third paragraph  of Remarks section http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx